# Delete folders which not match a list

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need practical example how get rid folders which are not in the list in Linux.
So i do not need to compare its contents or md5sums, just compare folders names.

For example, one folder has few folders inside

```
target_folder/
├── folder1
├── folder2
├── folder3
└── folder4
```

and my folders name list is txt file, includes folder1, folder2 and not folder3 and folder4.

How to remove folder3 and folder4 via bash script?

This has been answered on serverfault as

```
GLOBIGNORE=folder1:folder2
rm -r *
uset GLOBIGNORE
```

but my real task to delete bunch of folders.  The txt list contains around 100 folders and target folder to clean is 200 folders.

Note that this should work both in Linux and FreeBSD.

**EDIT:**
target_folder may contain folders with sub-folders and also files. No spaces and leading dots and names are not similar: foo.com bar.org emptydir file.txt simplefile. But all these items should be deleted except those names in the list.

First answer is more obvious and simple. Second one more advanced and flexible, it allows you to delete based on item type as well.

Comment: Take a look at bash's environment variable `$GLOBIGNORE`.

Comment: In what UNIX? Or do you mean Linux? The versions of the various tools are different in different operating systems.

Comment: @terdon, I mentioned that i need bash script it does not matter where it installed Unix or Linux.

Comment: It matters a lot. Tools like `find` which could be very useful here behave differently on different *nix operating systems. Please always include your OS.

Comment: @terdon you right, i meant bash behavior, not tools like find.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your answer and tell us your operating system. That will tell us what tools you have. We also need to know if your folders can be subfolders. Could you have `/foo/bar/` and want to delete `bar` only for example?

Comment: @terdon, done. As soon as i testing this on Linux, but i have also server on FreeBSD where probably also will require this later.

Comment: Folders with subfolders, but i need delete all of them regardless how many subfolders they have.

Comment: @Demontager thanks, you see FreeBSD is very different to Linux and the obvious `find` approach won't work there. Please also show us examples of your actual paths. Does your `name.txt` contain `folder1` or the full path (`target_folder/folder1`)?

Comment: @terdon, see second answer where i commented and showed screenshot of real paths. list.txt contains relative paths, so it is folder1 folder2

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include extra details. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read (no formatting) and can be deleted without warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your file names do not contain any of `:\[*?`, you could still use `GLOBIGNORE`. Just format your list of directories accordingly. For example:

```
$ cat names.txt
folder1
folder3
```

That is very easy to transform into a colon separated list:

```
$ paste -s -d : names.txt
folder1:folder3
```

So, you can now set that as the value of GLOBIGNORE:

```
GLOBIGNORE=$(paste -s -d : ../names.txt)
```

And proceed to delete them normally:

```
rm -r -- *
```

I just tested this on Linux with 300 directories and it worked perfectly.

Comment: i was thinking about how to convert list in row with colons, thanks for this great example. I tested on running server all done as expected.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
find ./target_folder/ \
    -mindepth 1 \
    -maxdepth 1 \
    -type d \
    -not -name 'anything[0-9]*' \
    -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Let me explain:

- `-mindepth 1` makes sure you don't match `./target_folder/`
- `-maxdepth 1` makes sure you don't match any subfolders.
- `-type d` tells find to only match directories, and not files.
- `-not -name 'anything[0-9]*'` excludes from the pattern anything that matches the pattern. Pretty obvious, that one.
- `-exec` is to be used with care, especially when it involves `rm`. 
  You should **always** test this using `echo` before going ahead and `rm -rf`ing stuff this way. `find` can be tricky to
- Don't forget the trailing `\;` when using exec.

You can read the `find` manual page for more info. It's an **extremely handy** tool.

Answer (score 3):

A simple approach is to list all files and ignore the ones that are in the list file. Note that I arrange for the variable `ignore_list` to start and end with a newline, so that I can check if `$x` is included in a simple way (just checking that `$ignore_list` contains `$x` doesn't work, since it would also match files whose name is a substring of an element of the ignore list).

```
newline='
'
ignore_list="$newline$(cat list.txt)$newline"
cd target_folder
for x in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
  case "$x" in *"$newline"*) continue;; esac   # sanity check: if the file name contains a newline, leave it alone
  case "$ignore_list" in
    *"$newline$x$newline"*) echo "Skipping $x";;
    *) rm -rf -- "$x";
  esac
done
```

Comment: Interesting approach as it does not involve conversion, but i tested and it deletes all folders and ignores my list. Of course before testing adjusted variables inside script.

Comment: @Demontager I just noticed a bug in my code: I used `*/` to match only directories in the target folder (and symbolic links to directories), but I forgot to strip it off. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect, it works as expected now. it will be in my scripts collections. I only can't get this variable  d=${d%/} its assignment. I checked by echoing it and it has folder names list which are ignored.

Comment: Also wanted to ask how to implement any file type here, i tested with folders and files and it deletes only folders.

Comment: @Demontager You asked for folders in your question, so I implemented this restriction. If you want to consider all files in `target_folder` and not just directories, change `for d in */; do` to `for d in *; do`. Note that dot files are ignored; if you want to remove them as well, change to `for d in * .[!.]* ..?*; do`

Comment: sure you done as asked. Edited main question and noted your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution that matches begin and end of the folder names:

```
IFS=$'\n'

folders="""folder1
folder2"""

for folder in *; do
    found=0
    if [ -d "$folder" ]; then
        for i in $folders; do
            if [ $(echo "$folder" | grep -c -E "^$i\$") -eq 1 ]; then
                found=1
            fi
        done
        if [ $found -ne 1 ]; then
            echo "$folder found and deleted."
            rm -rf "$folder"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that `""""foo""""` is not special, it's just the concatenation of `""` with `"foo"` and `""`, so the same as `"foo"`.

Comment: If your usage of `grep -E` is so that you can specify the list of folders as extended regular expressions, then you should rather do: `if ! printf '%s\n' "$folder" | grep -qxEe "$folders"; then rm -rf -- "$folder"; fi`. Though that won't work properly for file names that contain newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in bash like

```sh
for folder in /target_folder/*/
do
    folder=${folder%/}
    if ! grep -qx "${folder##*/}" folders_list.txt
    then
        rm -rf "$folder"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You can `find /target_folder -maxdepth 1 -type d | while IFS= read folder; do ... done` if the folder names contain spaces or start with a dot.

Comment: @Costas I tested your approach it deletes all folders. Also in my particular task folders are not named like folder1,2,3 they have not similar names. No spaces and dots before names, but they have dots inside like: bar.org  foo.com

Comment: @Demontager Suppose the problem in your `folder_list.txt` file. Check it by `grep "some_folder_name" folders_list.txt`

Comment: @Costas Double checked, my list.txt contains folder1 folder2 test.sh list.txt  now if i run it does nothing. Have a look on this http://simplest-image-hosting.net/jpeg-0-122mz

Comment: @Demontager I have check script againe and found logical mistake: reverse `grep` (with `-v` option) everytime is true because other lines in `folder_list.txt` is accepted to pattern. Repaired.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` (note that `GLOBIGNORE` is bash-specific, neither `bash` nor `zsh` are installed by default on FreeBSD, but both are available):

```
(cd /target_folder || exit
all_dirs=(*(/))
to_exclude=(${(f)"$(<names.txt))"})

rm -rf -- ${all_dirs:|to_exclude})
```

The `zsh`-specific features:

- `*(/)`. `(/)` is a *glob qualifier* that means only select the files of type *directory*.
- `$(<file)`: expands to the content (minus the trailing newline characters) of `file` (comes from `ksh`, `bash` also has it but does fork a process to read the content of `file` there).
- `${(f)...}`. That's a *parameter expansion flag* that splits the `"$(...)"` expansion on line feeds. With `bash`, you'd need to do something like: `IFS=$'\n'; set -f; to_exclude=($(<names.txt))` instead.
- `${A:|B}` expands to the elements of the `$A` array that are not also in the `$B` array.

Answer (score 0):

On a GNU or FreeBSD system, you can do:

```
cd /target_folder &&
  printf '%s\0' * | grep --null -vxFf names.txt | xargs -r0 rm -rf
```